# Galton Watson branching process: critical value and survival probability

Tags: probability, statistics

A Galton Watson branching process B is defined by p0 = 1/3 ;p1 = (1-c)*(2/3) and p2=c*(2/3) where pi is
the probability to have i offsprings ( c is [0;1] ).

a) compute the critical value c* such that for c<=c* the process B will die out with probability one and
for c > c* the process will survive with positive probability

b) compute the survival probability P1 that the process B starting with one individual will not die out as a function of c.

c) compute the survival probability P10 that the process B starting with 10 individuals will not die out.

I watched some videos on Galton Watson branching process, I understand what it is but I don't know how am I suppose to calculate survival probabilities, also I am not sure if I know what critical value is. If anyone knows some good papers on these topic I'm eager to read it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: the mean number of offspring is given by $m=0(1/3)+1(1-c)(2/3)+2c(2/3)=(2/3)(1+c)$. The process is subcritical if $m<1$ which means $c <1/2$. It is critical if $c=1/2$ and supercritical if $c >1/2$. For $c\leq 1/2$ extinction is certain and it is not certain if $c >1/2$. Hence the critical value $c^{*}$ is $1/2$.
 The extinction probability $q$ is the minimum of the the two roots of the equation $p_0+p_1s+p_2s^{2}=s$. Solving this quadratic equation we can write $q$ in terms of $c$. [ One root of the quadratic is always $1$ so it is easy to write down the other root. The answer to b) is simply $1-q$. For c) simply note that the probability that the  process becomes extinct when there are 10 individuals to start with equal to $q^{10}$ so the answer to c) is $1-q^{10}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your answer really helped me sir. I just don't understand one thing, could you please  explain how did you write the equation 0+1+2^2= ? Particularly, I don't understand where does "s" variable come from.

Comment: That is a theorem. Extinction probability is the smaller root of $f(s)=s$ where $f$ is the offspring generating function.

Comment: I see, so, if I understood correctly I input 1/3 as p0, (1-c)*(2/3) as p1 and (2/3)*C as p2 and then calculate  0+1+2^2 = 0 right?

Comment: The equation is $p_0+p_1s+p_2s^{2}=s$.